# Maven: How to use unmanaged dependencies on linux?

Tags: java, linux, maven

I tried to add unmanaged dependencies like described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies.

But it only works on Windows, not on linux.

**Project Structure**

```
|- src
  |- main
    |- java
      |- ...
    |- resources
|- libs
  |- net
    |- milkbowl
      |- Vault
        |- vault
          |- maven-metadata.xml
          |- ...
          |- 1.2.26-SNAPSHOT
            |- vault-1.2.26-SNAPSHOT.jar
            |- vault-1.2.26-SNAPSHOT.pom
            |- ...
|- pom.xml
```

**My POM:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    [...]
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>bukkit-repo</id>
            <url>http://repo.bukkit.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>local-dependencies</id>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/../libs/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.milkbowl.vault</groupId>
            <artifactId>vault</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.26-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    [...]
</project>
```

**Error:**  Missing artifact net.milkbowl.vault:vault:jar:1.2.26-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

get the jar first and then execute following maven goal to install that jar to your local repository

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/path/to/vault.jar -DgroupId=net.milkbowl.vault
-DartifactId=vault -Dversion=1.2.26-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar
```

if this goes `SUCCESSFUL`, then execute build again on your main project where this is define as dependency

Comment: did it install successfully ? if so can you see the file in ~/.m2/repository/net/milkbowl/vault/

Comment: and can you post the build log with `-X` flag passed

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UuhskD1W, but its only the stacktrace, because the build log is too long...

Comment: what was the maven goal you executed ?

Comment: somewhere in first 10 lines of log does it say `using local repository at` and is that path correct inside which you have that snapshot jar installed ?

Comment: I think I found the issue: 
`[DEBUG] Failure to find net.milkbowl.vault:vault:1.2.26-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in file:/<name>/<project>/libs/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of local-dependencies has elapsed or updates are forced`

Comment: oh so it needs metadata.xml file, it should create one when you install it, if not you can create similar file substituting parameters correctrly

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the root of your issue is the naming of the jar.  Having SNAPSHOT in the version tells maven to look for the newest snapshot in the repository.  Why don't you remove SNAPSHOT from the name, and try that.

Comment: Just to clarify, you'd have to remove SNAPSHOT from the jar name, the path to the jar, and change the dependency in your project's pom.xml.  Then you'd have to re-deploy the dependency, and rebuild your project.

Comment: Yes, I know, I renamed the path, the jar, some other files (like pom), and the dependency in project's pom.xml.

Comment: try removing the extra / in your repository definition. Not sure if it'll help but worth a shot.